# Compile a kernel using a custom file system type such as "myext4"

Tags: filesystems, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, ext4

Is it possible to take the source code of ext4, make no changes to it apart from changing its name to "myext4" and then compiling my kernel so that it accepts this custom file system type?

Is it as trivial as changing all the ext4 references in the ext4 source code to 
"myext4" (ex: changing names of files such as ext4.h to myext4.h)?
If not then what changes do i need to make to the source code of ext4 or the kernel for this to work?

Also i need the mkfs command to also work with these changes (mkfs.myext4 instead of mkfs.ext4).

Are there any resources available that would help me learn more about this particular topic?

Comment: This smells like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Just a wild guess, but I think whatever you want to achieve can be done in a more straightforward way.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to rename a lot of symbols in the code so that they don't clash with the existing Ext4 ones. If you want to experiment with the Ext4 filesystem, I would suggest you install Linux on a separate computer, using a different filesystem (e.g. btrfs) for /usr and /home. Then hack on the Ext4 code directly. Reserve a separate partition for testing your modified Ext4 filesystem.

There aren't many recent books on Linux kernel internals, but I would say the good old Linux Device Drivers 3rd edition is still useful.

Comment: Yes, of course.